# multi-boot machines with windows often won’t install updates properly

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 18.04,  Windows 10 setup.
I am unable to update Windows at all thanks to this problem.
It always starts updating and goes to around 10%.
After that, the PC completely shuts down.
Later, on restarting it says "Undoing updates".
I have seen the question asked on Windows forums but they don't seem to have any clue as to what is going on.

I tried to update once again.
This was the state before the update [image: state before the update]
As suggested by [bodo](https://superuser.com/users/992527/bodo), I checked the Windows event logs and found that my computer faced the error code 0xC1900101, 0x8024402F
[image: 0xC1900101] [image: 0x8024402F].Strangely it says [image: successful update], but it usually changes its mind later.

Comment: Do you think it is related to using dual-boot? (Why?) Did you check the Windows event log for error reports? Please don't use comments to answer, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: How do I see the Windows event logs?

Comment: Press the Windows key once, then type "event". , then it should list the event log viewer. See e.g. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-event-viewer-windows-10